# What if array name is put in square brackets?

Tags: arrays, c

I saw such a piece of C code:

```
int main()
{
    static int a[] = {7,8,9};
    printf("%d", 2[a] + a[2]);;
    
    return 0;
}
```

What does `2[a]`  mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[b]` and `b[a]` are 100% equivalent in C. What you have there is a very unidiomatic way of writing `a[2]`.

By way of more complete explanation, array subscript notation `a[b]` is also 100% equivalent to `*(a + b)`, which may make the reason it works both ways clearer.

Comment: If a and b are expressions then in general a[b] is not equivalent to b[a].